# How to make a column value copyable and not editable in Ag-grid - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a javascript grid (ag grid)

```
       var columnDefinitions = [
        {
            headerName: 'Item Number',
            field: 'ItemNumber',
            width: 140,
            editable: editable && status !== 'Open',
            cellClass: 'ag-autocomplete',
            cellEditor:Grids.CellEditors.ItemEditor({
                updateCallback: function (rowData, selectedItem) {
                    rowData.ItemId = selectedItem.Id;
                    rowData.Description = selectedItem.Description;
                },
                getInitialFilters: function () {
                    return [
                        { Identifier: "VId", Values: [$("#Id").val()] }
                    ];
                },
                searchDefinition: 'InvItems.json',
                autocompleteSearchDefinition: 'InvDetail.json'
            })
        },
        .....
        {
            headerName: 'Tracking Number',
            field: 'TrackingNumber',
            width: 120,
            cellRenderer: function (params) {
                if (params.data.TrackingNumber != null) {
                    var url;
                    if (params.data.Carrier == 'UPS') {
                        url = 'https://wwwapps.ups.com/tracking/tracking.cgi?tracknum=';
                    }
                    if (params.data.Carrier == 'USPS') {
                        url = 'https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tLabels=';
                    }
                    return "<a target='_blank' href='" + url
                        + params.value
                        + "'>" + params.value + "</a>";
                }
                else {
                    return '';
                }
            }
        },
```

I want to make the column "TrackingNumber" copyable. I don't want to make it editable. anything I try that make it like a textbox and I can copy the value I can edit it too that I don't want that.

Comment: I am not familiar with ag-grid, look for readonly property. Usually, with input element, readonly attribute does the job

Comment: what do your grid options look like? are you setting full row edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

Add `enableCellTextSelection: true` to your grid options. [Docs here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/selection-overview/#cell-text-selection)

Comment: I saw this before and added t is not working for me.